# open PDF with PDFKit.PDFView on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, xamarin.ios, ios-pdfkit

I have an application with PDF viewer, and I try to use `PDFKit.PDFView` which need to `PDFKit.PDFDocument` object.

My code is:

```
var pdfview = new PdfKit.PdfView();
var path = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("Harvard", "pdf");
var urll = new NSUrl(path);
var pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(urll);
pdfview.Document = pdfdoc;
```

I get an exception at line 4, which says :

> Could not initialize an instance of the type 'PdfKit.PdfDocument': the
>   native 'initWithURL:' method returned nil

My pdf file, Harvard.pdf, is in Resources folder and in direct iOS project directory with BundleResource build action.

this PDF file can be read easily with `CGPDFDocument`, but I need to use `PDFView` to solve problem I asked for it before in 
[handle links clicking inside PDF viewer on iOS with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575281/handle-links-clicking-inside-pdf-viewer-on-ios-with-swift).
So, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with follow way to check whether `URL` return `nil`:

```
var documentURL = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("Harvard", "pdf");
var pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(documentURL);
```

This is full sample code :

```
var documentURL = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("MyForm", "pdf");
if (documentURL != null)
{
    var document = new PdfDocument(documentURL);
    //var page = document.GetPage(0);

    var pdfview = new PdfKit.PdfView();
    pdfview.Frame = View.Frame;
    pdfview.Document = document;
    pdfview.AutoScales = true;
    pdfview.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    pdfview.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;

    View.AddSubview(pdfview);
}
```

And effect ：

[image]

Comment: well,it works fine.but I have a question, when I'm debugging to see the difference between NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource and NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource, it was that the second returns "file:///" in the start of URL. Now I need your help to open the PDF from device storage if you can help me please, the URL in simulator is "/Users/haykalmedia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DA58EBD1-0328-409A-8F95-63E3FFAE456F/data/Containers/Data/Application/1E65FD74-8080-4FE6-BF30-554B6E11424D/Documents/Harvard_26_M-1.pdf", I tried to add "file:///" to its start, but it does not work.

Comment: @LofiMAM If add `file://` before path string , it will work as the same with `GetUrlForResource`. I think here you add one more `/` .At the start of path string , there is a `/` exists . So remove the extra `/` , it will works :)

Comment: thanks a lot, I knew it and tried it, but unfortunately it does not work, so I used var data = new NSData(url); var document = new PDFDocument(data); and it works fine. thank you man, you saved me.

Comment: there is a difference between resources path and storage path (where my actual file is in storage not in resources which means I did not need resources path).

Comment: @LofiMAM Yes , they are different . You can have a look at this doc about path in iOS .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories

Comment: Hello, please I need your help again. PDFView class has an function called UsePageViewController with two parameters, I need to use the second parameter which named viewOptions of type NSDictionary, I need use it to set the following UIPageViewContoller properties : "TransitionStyle, NavigationOrientation".That if I can. I made some searches and I did not get a useful results. And thank you.

Comment: @LofiMAM You can create a new question in SO to explain this detailly, then I will check that in new question :-)

Comment: well, I will do it soon and I will tell you.